# How to save sharepoint pages to my own computer

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can i save SharePoint pages to my own computer.

Greetings,

Peter

Comment: hi Peter, what kind of SharePoint version are you using? On-prem/online? Are you talking about Classic or Modern Pages? Are these pages with just text or they contain images and webparts? Why do you want to save these pages? what is the purpose? Do you want to restore these pages elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use [SharePoint designer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491) to export pages, try as follows:

[image]